# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django

I am trying to use a context processor to get the last 10 messages based on the user's organization.  What is weird is that I can call self in get_user, but i can't in get_last_10_messages.  Any ideas why I get the WSGIRequest issue in one function and not the other?

```
from message.models import Message
from contact.models import Contact

def get_last_10_messages(self):

    print(self.request.user.id)
    user = Contact.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id).select_related('organization')

    last_10_messages = Message.objects.all()
    return {'last_messages': last_10_messages}

def get_user(self):

    user = Contact.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id).select_related('organization')

    return {'user': user}
```

Comment: The argument passed to context processors is the request itself. Your functions aren't class instance methods, you should probably rename the parameter in your functions from "self" to "request" to avoid this confusion

Answer (score 0):

Because a `request` has no `.request`. You named your request `self` instead of calling it `request`.

[self](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why) is a parameter in methods only which refers to the current instance of the class.